# How to use onSaveInstanceState with a lot of data and objects

Tags: android

When my application became sophisticated and main activity started holding in memory a lot of data (loaded and parsed from files in response to user actions) I have (mistakenly) switched from `onSaveInstanceState` to `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance` without noticing that `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance` is not called when application is killed to save device memory. So as now I has to switch back to `onSaveInstanceState` I want to as what is the proper way to handle a huge amount of data distributed by tens of objects? Do I have to implement serialization for all these objects (`Parcelable`?) or may be put all the data into `Service` thread hoping it would not be killed? What is the best practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended with an ugly but the only acceptable solution:

1. I've moved all the data into `Application` object.
2. I've created a foreground `Service` so that application object will not be killed even if all activities are killed.

Answer (score 1):

`onRetainNonConfigurationInstance` is deprecated. Now it is better and easier to use the [new Fragment API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html). Basically, you extend the `Fragment` class, call [`setRetainInstance(true)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setRetainInstance%28boolean%29), and put all the variables you want to save here (well it's a bit more complicated but [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html) is very clear and provides several samples).

It was introduced in API 11 but is available on older platforms through the Android compatibility package.